# pass id & content of textarea element via ajax post method using sweetalert version 2

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, sweetalert2

```js
function answerTheQuestion(id) {
        swal({
            title: "enter complaint",
            input: "textarea",
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: "#DD8B11",
            confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
            closeOnConfirm: false
        }).then(function(text) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "../ajax/ajax_active_deact.php?type=complaint_answered",
                data: {complaint_id: id, myContentText: text},
                cache: false,
                success: function(response) {
                    swal(
                        "success!",
                        "your note has been saved!",
                        "success"
                    )
                },
                failure: function(response) {
                    swal(
                        "Internal error",
                        "oops, your note was not saved",
                        "error"
                    )
                }
            });
        },
        function(dismiss) {
            if(dismiss === "cancel") {
                swal(
                    "Cancelled",
                    "cancelled note",
                    "error"
                )
            }
        });
    }
```

```html
<button class='btn btn-xs btn-info2'                onclick='answerTheQuestion($complaint->complaint_id)'                   data- tooltip='tooltip'  title='open the form for answered the complaint' >
 <i class='ace-icon fa fa-edit bigger-120'></i>
</button>
```

1. when I clicked the button it triggers answerTheQuestion() function.
2. I pass the relevant id to this function.
3. when the function executes, I want to open a sweet-alert with textarea 
   element inside it.
4. when the save button clicked I want to send ajax POST request along with id & content of text area.
5. I tried and can't get around how to do this.
6. kindly, appreciate you'r advises how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

few things that i found missing in your code are:

1) csrf_token to be send in data with complaint_id  & myContentText.

2) complaint_id must be in inverted commas.

3) myContentText must be inverted commas.

If swal({}).then(function(){}) doesnot work try using swal({},function(){}).

Comment: @pradumn I tried but it shows only title, not a textarea.

Comment: For text are instead of input try text : <textarea id = "text"></textarea>.